# Jersey, Tomcat and Security Annotations

Tags: tomcat, annotations, jersey

I need to secure a simple Jersey RESTful API in a Tomcat 6.0.24 container. I'd like to keep the authentication with Basic Authentication using the `tomcat-users.xml` file to define the users and roles (this is for now, like I said it's small).

Now, for authorization I'd like to be able to use the JSR 250 annotations like `@RolesAllowed`, `@PermitAll`, `@DenyAll`, etc.

I cannot for the life of me figure out how to wire this all up together.

I really don't want to go the Spring Security route, since I need something very simple at the current time.

Can someone point me in the right direction?

Comment: Since you tagged this question with `spring` and `spring-security` but you instead stated that you don't want to use it, are you actually using spring? If not, just leave them away.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16433315/can-i-use-rolesallowed-on-restful-resources-implemented-on-apache-cxf

Answer (score 1):

You can start with using a filter which covers the authentication and privilege management at first.
with implemeting ResourceFilter and  ContainerRequestFilter, you ability to get httpRequest, sessions then redirects your application/requests to related methods.

For privilege management you can implement SecurityContext filter. you have to check isUserInRole at first to let request go inside method.

Here is the sample for SecurityContext implementation:

```
 public class SecurityContextImpl implements SecurityContext {

    private final SessionUser user;

    public SecurityContextImpl(SessionUser user) {
        this.user = user;
    }

    public Principal getUserPrincipal() {
        return user;
    }

    public boolean isUserInRole(String role) {

        if(user == null) {
            throw new AuthenticationException();
        }
        if(ObjectUtil.isNull(user.getPrivileges())){
            throw new AuthenticationException();
        }
        if(!user.getPrivileges().contains(role)) {
            throw new InvalidAuthorizationHeaderException();
        }
        return user.getPrivileges().contains(role);
    }

    public boolean isSecure() {
        return false;
    }

    public String getAuthenticationScheme() {
        return SecurityContext.BASIC_AUTH;
    }
}
```

Here is the basic SecurityContextFilter implementation :

```
    public class SecurityContextFilter implements ResourceFilter, ContainerRequestFilter {

    private static final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(SecurityContextFilter.class);

    protected static final String HEADER_AUTHORIZATION = "Authorization";

    protected static final String HEADER_DATE = "x-java-rest-date";

    protected static final String HEADER_NONCE = "nonce";


    private HttpServletRequest httpRequest;




    public SecurityContextFilter() {


    }


    public ContainerRequest filter(ContainerRequest request) {

        SessionUser sessionUser = (SessionUser) httpRequest
                .getSession()
                .getAttribute("sessionUser");

        request.setSecurityContext(new SecurityContextImpl(sessionUser));

        return request;
    }


    public ContainerRequestFilter getRequestFilter() {
        return this;
    }

    public ContainerResponseFilter getResponseFilter() {
        return null;
    }

    public HttpServletRequest getHttpRequest() {
        return httpRequest;
    }

    public void setHttpRequest(HttpServletRequest httpRequest) {
        this.httpRequest = httpRequest;
    }


}
```

Do not forget to put your filter as an init-param inside the web.xml,

Then you can handle request with your role-privilege-authentication logic.