# Jersey client basic http authentication on https to glassfish monitoring resources

Tags: java, authentication, https, glassfish, jersey

I have a jersey client code that tries to access glassfish monitoring api, glassfish has secure admin (ssl+basic auth). Glassfish returns "Invalid user name or password" for correct credentials when using authentication.

I can gain access to unsecured glassfish without any problems. I have ssl certificates set up (calling from the same jvm - and handshake passes), and when trying to access resource with a browser - it works.

I am using glassfish 3.1.1 and tried jersey client with both bundled 1.8 and with 1.11 (so both versions where supposedly httpBasicAuth bug is fixed)

my code is:

```
WebResource resource = restClient.resource(uri);        
    if(userName != null || password != null){
        resource.addFilter(new HTTPBasicAuthFilter(userName, password));
    }
    ClientResponse result = resource.accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).get(ClientResponse.class);
```

and response is:

```
{"message":"Invalid user name or password","command":"Error","exit_code":"FAILURE"}
```

And yes - password, username, url have been checked more than 3 times by more than 3 people.

This question is similiar, but still unanswered: [Authentication problem using Jersey and Glassfish](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5938919/authentication-problem-using-jersey-and-glassfish)