# Jersey JAX-RS + Spring security application sample

Tags: java, spring-security, jersey, restful-authentication

Does anyone have a sample application about what is described on this answer?

[User authentication on a Jersey REST service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2902427/user-authentication-on-a-jersey-rest-service/2903167#2903167)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use Followings Steps:

- **Step 1**. Insert a Filter(See Jersey DOCS how to intercept request) in your jersey Application.
- **Step 2**. Ask client application to pass user credentials in Header, So that you fetch them in Jersey Service Filter.
- **Step 3**. Fetch the header values and ask your DB to validate them.
- **Step 4**. Once validated use Security Context to store the principle(User).
- **Step 5**. Use stored Security Context to validate your Jersey Service sub-resource.

Follow my steps and you will achieve your answer.