# Securing JaxRs Webservices with advance authentication methods like LDAP

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, ldap, jax-rs

In My application I am using spring controller along with service layer using jaxrs.I am Planing to use some advance and fast authentication method using LDAP extra layer.Is spring security will helpful for securing my webservices?for authentication?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Jersey JAX-RS + Spring security application sample](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6795568/jersey-jax-rs-spring-security-application-sample)

Comment: also useful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2902427/user-authentication-on-a-jersey-rest-service/2903167#2903167