# How to write android client server application?

Tags: android

I want to write an android application which works with some server in which app will query to server and server will reply with few objects.

I have tested login functionality with Java servlet using following method.

```
http://myhost:8080/androidapp/login?username='myusername'&password='mypassword'
```

But it seems that this is not the secure way to do such transactions. Any way user will not be able to see this information but still I want to know that is it secure to use this method.

When project will grow server will send many objects and android app also will need to send too many parameters so I think above method is useless.

Please suggest me some method through which I can get my work done easily without going into other technology like php etc. because I am already working with JSF and android client app side so it would be difficult for me to learn new things in short time.

Other option which I though is to use RMI (Remote Method Invocation) but how can I use it in eclipse or will it supported by Apache Tomcat?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can recommend using a RESTful WebApplication on server-side. Your Android app can easily be tought to interact with your server, and your server (which is a tomcat as you say) can easily be a RESTful Webserver by using the Jersey framework as REST API. The authentication process for Jersey is described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2902427/user-authentication-on-a-jersey-rest-service) for example. A tutorial for building a RESTful WebApp can be found [here](http://www.vogella.com/articles/REST/article.html) along with other useful tutorials.

But be aware of the fact, that REST is a paradigm that has to be fully understanded before building it.

Comment: Hmmm I think this is the best choice currently that I have... Thanks...