# Can I use @RolesAllowed on RESTful Resources implemented on Apache CXF?

Tags: rest, jersey, authorization, cxf, jax-rs

My question is 
**"Can I use @RolesAllowed on RESTful Resources implemented on CXF  ?"**.

First of all, I explain the context causing this question.
I'm working at some projects in which developers have to remake one part of the some web systems into `RESTful` WEB Apis.This present system has server system built by `Spring` and `Hibernate`. And its client application as UI is developed by `ActionScript` through 
`FLEX framework`.
Now I'm surveying the proper way to design and remake our present system into `RESTful APIs` through reading some documents or develop some prototypes.So, we temporarily decided to use `Apache-CXF ver.2.7.4` as `JAX-RS` implementation and `TOMCAT ver.7` as Web applications container.

Then, I am struggling for the way of user authorizations now.
As you know, I mean the word `'Authorization'` as some control mechanism that constrain some users to access functions according to user's roll like `ROLE_ADMIN`, `ROLL_EMPLOYEE` and so on.And our team wants to use `@RolesAllowed` annotation to constrain user to access some RESTful methods in `REST` resource classes.
Through surveying, I knew that we can use `@RolesAllowed` annotation if we use `Jersey` as `JAX-RS` imple and TOMCAT, because Jersey framework provides

[com.sun.jersey.api.container.filter.RolesAllowedResourceFilterFactory](https://jersey.java.net/nonav/apidocs/1.1.1-ea/jersey/com/sun/jersey/api/container/filter/RolesAllowedResourceFilterFactory.html)

for developers to activate @RolesAllowed annotation by adding following lines in web.xml

```
<init-param>
  <param-name>com.sun.jersey.spi.container.ResourceFilters</param-name> 
  <param-value>
    com.sun.jersey.api.container.filter.RolesAllowedResourceFilterFactory
  </param-value>
</init-param>
```

as init-param of jersey's ServletContainer.

But our team has decided `Apache CXF` as JAX-RS imple.I've already surveyed the security and authorization parts of web documents in CXF site. But I couldn’t get solutions or how to use `@RolesAllowed` on RESTful resource methods.

So If you know the requirements or how to use `@RolesAllowed` on RESTful resource implemented on `Apache CXF` and `TOMCAT`, teach me that, please.Or if you can definitively conclude that we can't use `@RolesAllowed` in frameworks choice of `Apache CXF` and `TOMCAT`, please teach me the background knowledge of that conclusion.

Additionally, I suppose that I can use `@RolesAllowed` in REST resource by `CXF` on `JBOSS` as app server, not on `TOMCAT`. Is this assumption true ? I'm sorry that I've not made a trial to use `JBOSS` instead of TOMCAT.

Best regards.

Comment: Were you able to make any progress on this question?  I'm asking exactly the same question @ the moment and researching options.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, this can be done.  I'll assume that you (like me) did not want to use Spring Security as part of the solution (to handle authentication and authorization) since there seems to be plenty of resources on how to enable the JSR-250 annotations with Spring Security.

My solution began with a simple JAX-RS project built from the CXF-supplied Archetype Project `org.apache.cxf.archetype:cxf-jaxrs-service:2.7.5` (lastest GAV @ time of writing).

This gives you a basic `HelloWorld` class with supporting config files.

A few modifications need to be made.

First, add the following dependencies to the `pom.xml`:

```xml
<dependency>
  <groupId>javax.annotation</groupId>
  <artifactId>jsr250-api</artifactId>
  <version>1.0</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
  <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
  <version>3.0.1</version>
  <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

Why?  Because Tomcat is not a full J2EE Container, it does not support all JSR-250 Annotations (of which `@RolesAllowed` is one).  Further, although CXF recognizes and will work with `@RolesAllowed`, it does not bundle an implementation, expecting it to be provided by either a J2EE container or the inclusion of the api as above.

The `servlet-api` is listed because I needed it at compile time for a method I add to `HellowWorld.java` (see below).

Second, modify `beans.xml` as follows:

```xml
<bean class="my.pkg.HelloWorld" id="helloWorldService"/>

<jaxrs:serviceBeans>
   <ref bean="helloWorldService"/>
</jaxrs:serviceBeans>

<bean id="authorizationInterceptor"
      class="org.apache.cxf.interceptor.security.SecureAnnotationsInterceptor">
  <property name="securedObject" ref="helloWorldService" />
</bean>
```

The `SecureAnnotationsInterceptor` is what will scan the `helloWorldService` and enforce the `@RolesAllowed` annotations.

Note that the `helloWorldService` had to be pulled out of the `<jaxrs:serviceBeans>` stanza so it could be referenced both there and in the `authorizationInterceptor`.

Third, add some roles and users to `tomcat-users.xml` or alternative (e.g. JDBC Realm, etc.)  I did this:

```xml
<role rolename="hello-user" />
<role rolename="hello-role1"/>
<role rolename="hello-role2" />
<user username="hello1" password="Password1" roles="hello-role1,hello-user"/>
<user username="hello2" password="Password1" roles="hello-role2,hello-user"/>
```

This creates 2 users who each have a shared role (`hello-user`) plus  their own distinct role.

Fourth, add the following to `web.xml` to enable `BASIC` authentication:

```xml
<security-constraint>
    <web-resource-collection>
        <web-resource-name>Hello Services</web-resource-name>
        <url-pattern>/hello/*</url-pattern>
    </web-resource-collection>
    <auth-constraint>
        <role-name>hello-user</role-name>
    </auth-constraint>
</security-constraint>
<login-config>
    <auth-method>BASIC</auth-method>
    <realm-name>default</realm-name>
</login-config>
```

With this, I decided to require the role `hello-user` for everything under `/hello/*`.  That's not essential, but beware that I did have some issues omitting some of the stanzas, wildcards and roles... so experiment with care here.

Fifthly (and finally), mark up the `HelloWorld.java` class:

```java
@Path("/hello")
@RolesAllowed("hello-user")
public class HelloWorld {

    @GET
    @Path("/echo/{input}")
    @Produces("text/plain")
    @RolesAllowed("hello-role1") 
    public String ping(@PathParam("input") String input) {
        return input;
    }

    @POST
    @Produces("application/json")
    @Consumes("application/json")
    @Path("/jsonBean")
    @RolesAllowed("hello-role2") 
    public Response modifyJson(JsonBean input) {
        input.setVal2(input.getVal1());
        return Response.ok().entity(input).build();
    }

    @GET
    @Produces("text/plain")
    @Path("/cliche")
    public Response getClichedMessage(@Context HttpServletRequest request) {
            return Response.
                    ok().
                    entity("Sending \"Hello World\" to user \"" + request.getUserPrincipal().getName() + "\"").
                    build();
    }
}
```

I added the last method (`getClichedMessage()`) to show that both users can access the method because they have the `hello-user` role with which the class is annotated.  The `SecureAnnotationsInterceptor` is smart enough to handle that.

That's all.  Seems to me, this is the STTCPW using just Tomcat, CXF and BASIC authentication.  The key for the CXF + `@RolesAllowed` is the `SecureAnnotationsInterceptor`.

**Update**:  I should acknowledge that [Converting Jersey REST Examples to Apache CXF](http://www.jroller.com/gmazza/entry/jersey_samples_on_cxf) was particularly helpful, especially for pointing out the SecureAnnotationsInterceptor whose connection to `@RolesAllowed` is not well documented elsewhere.

**Update 2**: The Jersey-CXF blog entry doesn't seem be migrated to [`gmazza`'s new blog](https://web-gmazza.rhcloud.com/).  However, the [example I used is on github](https://github.com/gmazza/jersey-samples-on-cxf/tree/master/https-server-glassfish).  It contains a [config file with `SecureAnnotationsInterceptor` definition](https://github.com/gmazza/jersey-samples-on-cxf/blob/master/https-server-glassfish/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/beans.xml) and a [bean with `@RolesAllowed` annotation](https://github.com/gmazza/jersey-samples-on-cxf/blob/master/https-server-glassfish/src/main/java/com/sun/jersey/samples/https_glassfish/resources/HelloWorldResource.java)

Comment: The link is broken. I know it was updated 3 years back. See if you find and update the correct link

Comment: I still have the (old) source code up for now as Jacob noted, but removed the blog article itself as it was out-of-date and high maintenance/low reward.